# Ignite loadCache performance issue

Tags: caching, ignite

I have a 3rd party Mysql table that will be cached partially by Ignite cluster. So on ignite, I have done this conf:

```
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                    <property name="multicastGroup" value="228.10.10.157" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="clientMode" value="true" />
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="crmdbcache" />
                <property name="onheapCacheEnabled" value="true" />
                <property name="readThrough" value="true" />
                <property name="readFromBackup" value="false" />
                <property name="evictionPolicy">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.eviction.lru.LruEvictionPolicy">
                        <property name="maxSize" value="100" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="indexedTypes">
                    <list>
                        <value>java.lang.Long</value>
                        <value>com.example.demo.UserSegment</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
                <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory">
                        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
                        <property name="dialect">
                            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.dialect.MySQLDialect"></bean>
                        </property>
                        <property name="parallelLoadCacheMinimumThreshold" value="20"/>
                        <property name="types">
                            <list>
                                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcType">
                                    <property name="databaseSchema" value="crm" />
                                    <property name="databaseTable" value="CRM_SEGMENT" />
                                    <property name="cacheName" value="crmdbcache" />
                                    <property name="keyType" value="java.lang.Long" />
                                    <property name="valueType" value="com.example.demo.UserSegment" />
                                    <property name="keyFields">
                                        <list>
                                            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcTypeField">
                                                <constructor-arg index="0" value="-5" />
                                                <constructor-arg index="1" value="USER_ID" />
                                                <constructor-arg index="2" value="java.lang.Long" />
                                                <constructor-arg index="3" value="userId" />
                                            </bean>
                                        </list>
                                    </property>
                                    <property name="valueFields">
                                        <list>
                                            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcTypeField">
                                                <constructor-arg index="0" value="-5" />
                                                <constructor-arg index="1" value="ID" />
                                                <constructor-arg index="2" value="java.lang.Long" />
                                                <constructor-arg index="3" value="id" />
                                            </bean>
                                            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcTypeField">
                                                <constructor-arg index="0" value="-5" />
                                                <constructor-arg index="1" value="USER_ID" />
                                                <constructor-arg index="2" value="java.lang.Long" />
                                                <constructor-arg index="3" value="userId" />
                                            </bean>
                                            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcTypeField">
                                                <constructor-arg index="0" value="-5" />
                                                <constructor-arg index="1" value="TYPE_ID" />
                                                <constructor-arg index="2" value="java.lang.Long" />
                                                <constructor-arg index="3" value="type" />
                                            </bean>
                                            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcTypeField">
                                                <constructor-arg index="0" value="12" />
                                                <constructor-arg index="1" value="TAG" />
                                                <constructor-arg index="2" value="java.lang.String" />
                                                <constructor-arg index="3" value="tag" />
                                            </bean>
                                        </list>
                                    </property>
                                </bean>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

So , I am also inspecting the load over ignitevisor. But it seems , it is very slow. I have also run ignite.sh vith -v option but there seems no problem.

So my question is: am I missing something or where should I start to look for the problem?

EDIT: It has written only 640 items in 1 minute. Increasing of thread count did not effect performance at all. Database has 3.2 million records and I want to add 100K of them in cache based on LRU. But with this performance, it seems it will continue like forever

Comment: First of all, how do you define "slow"? Do you have any particular expectations and if yes, what are they based on? How far is the result from these expectations?

Comment: @ValentinKulichenko you are right, I have missed that part. Please see the edit.

Comment: First of all, I would check if database is not a bottleneck. Try to fetch the same data from DB to the same physical location where Ignite nodes are, but using plain JDBC driver. How long does this take?